# codeigniter redirect not working on server

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo una aplicación hecha con Codeigniter, y en local me funciona todo correctamente, pero al subirla al servidor, los redirect no funcionan y me da un error 500.
¿Qué puede estar pasando?

Comment: Sólo trabajé una vez con CI hace algún tiempo y creo recordar que fue algo del htaccess... Quizá esto te ayude

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504282/500-internal-server-error-codeigniter-htaccess-mod-rewrite

Comment: Acabo de comprobar que me funciona si en la url pongo index.php y sin él no me funciona...

Comment: Mira a ver entonces si en la configuración del servidor (apache/iis) tienes puesto que por defecto busque, además del tipico index.html, default.html, que también busque index.php.
Y si no, algo del htaccess...

Comment: Como tienes los `redirect`, puedes agregarlos a tu pregunta.

Comment: Existen dos formas de trabajar con las url's en CI, una es usando el Index.php o utilizar url amigables, pienso que primero deberías ver cual vas ocupar, ya que las dos tienen diferentes forma de configurar.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, ya encontré la solución, y es que en el servidor los ficheros que son controladores y modelos deben empezar por mayúsculas, y en local no importa, por eso no me funcionaba.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero pruebes lo siguiente:
en la raíz del proyecto edita tu archivo .htacces o si no lo tienes lo creas y pegas el siguiente contenido

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Y posteriormente en la ruta /application/config/config.php
en la linea 38 la editas que quede de la siguiente manera

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

con esto debería ser suficiente para que funcione.
No está de más recordar que en el mismo archivo en la linea 26 debes configurar el BASE URL